# How to enable autocomplete in Chrome Developer Tools console for let and const variables?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6

In ES6 recommended declare variables with `let` and `const` with thin `var`. But Google Chrome haven't autocomplete for this variables. (maybe it can only autocomplete global scope).
Firefox autocomplete this type of variables fine.

How i can enable autocomplete in console for this type of variables? If i can't - when it will be worked?

p.s. i find one old question, but not any worked answered(

Comment: what do you mean by autocomplete in this context? autocomplete to complete partially typed `let` and `const` keywords? To complete variable names? To complete values to assign to the variables?